# Are there situations where you have to absolutely put a comma before because?

Tags: punctuation

> You shouldn't report him because he's a relative. You should report him for other reasons.
>
> You shouldn't report him, because he's a relative. You shouldn't report him because he's a relative.

I am pretty sure you can always put a comma before because and change the meaning of the sentence, but I am wondering if there are cases where only one meaning is possible and therefore you have to put a comma before because because the other meaning (where we don't put a comma) is meaningless.

Comment: You seem to be arguing that comma use before "because" is never optional. Is that right?

Comment: You seem to understand the difference which the comma makes. It's impossible to answer your question without spending a long time thinking of possible sentences containing _because_, which I'm sure you can do as well as anyone else here.